# Making a small drain/vent/hole in a glass box

Tags: water, drill, drainage, glass, materials

I've got a glass box that measures 900mm x 450mm x 450mm.

The width of the glass is about 6mm thick.

If I drill, cut, or grind a small hole in/through one of the faces; will it significantly affect the structural integrity of that piece of glass?

I'm concerned it might become prone to flexing, and cracking; if I pick it up to move (or transport) it, for instance.

Is there some kind of ratio, or formula that I can use to determine a relatively safe size, and adjacent edge distance for an aperture?

If you're wondering: It's basically a small indoor display garden / vivarium type situation, which needs at least a single outlet point through which gravity can be allowed to drain the excess fluids from the soil.

[image: glass box schematic diagram]

Comment: Some people are getting a little over-zealous in the close flag.  3 votes to close as arts/crafts/decorating advice.  READ THE QUESTION PEOPLE - it's a question about STRUCTURAL INTEGRITY.  It belongs in engineering! ;)

Comment: It's a simple question about drilling a drain into a glass fixture. It's going to be mounted in a new wall as a display feature.

Comment: Exactly - I'm joking about moving it to Engineering - just coming down on the over zealous close votes because your project is artistic - just cause it's pretty doesn't mean questions about it don't fit here.

Comment: I am assuming that this is not intended to carry any kind of load.  Why do you wish to drill a hole?

Comment: You cannot [drill a hole in tempered glass](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/90131/how-can-i-drill-a-hole-in-tempered-glass-without-shattering-it?rq=1) without shattering it.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo I appreciate that. It's what I've come to expect on SE, unfortunately. I actually asked the Engineering guys a similar question a while back, but I think they missed the point. So now I'm asking the Home Improvement/DIY crowd; I figured I'd get some more pragmatic, practical advice from the guys with their hands on the tools.

Comment: It will inevitably have to support the weight of its contents, but it's not like an aquarium that has to hold gallons of water.

Comment: Why do I want to drill a hole? Basically, there needs to be an egress point for condensed water vapour, and any other fluids that would otherwise accumulate, saturate the contents, and eventually lead to biological problems like bacteria and rot.

Comment: Ah I see - missed the intended use earlier.  Sounds neat!

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo No worries, I might have added that information after. I generally try to omit non-essential details like that so that it can apply to as many people/projects as possible. Also, so people don't get distracted from the actual question, and try to handball me to another site; like Pets, Gardening, Biology, Engineering, and so on.

Comment: Agreed. OPs shouldn't have to lie to us. "I've got a 1/4" thick glass... uh, 'counter top'. Where can I drill a hole?"

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot cite any specific sources for this, I'm going to posit the following answer:

Yes, structural integrity will be affected, but **not enough to be concerned about.**

The box you describe is not suitable for carrying any kind of load anyway, and as you state above it's for display purposes.  Drilling a tiny hole will not cause any cracking - in fact it's a technique used in windshields (particularly aviation windshields used in small planes) to STOP cracks from continuing to spread.  (Small hole drilled right at the leading edge of an expanding crack relieves the stresses in a sound manner)

Granted aviation glass is different than what you've got but still - I think you're fine.  I'm curious though why drill a hole in it?  That will have a tendency to trap moisture.

Comment: Well, yeah; it *is* for display purposes, so it has to support the items on display, It generally won't be *carrying* a load from one place to another; but it will be mostly suspended over a gap, with support under the edges. Also, I have prior experience with this (almost) exact project, but generally a bit smaller, and always with some kind of clear, molded plastic. Drilling a drainage hole will solve the problem; I learned that the hard way. It's just that I have no experience working with glass.

Answer (score 1):

Once you successfully (!) get the hole drilled, there's little concern. Not cracking it while you drill it is the hard part.

I'd say ~2 inches in from a corner, or at least an inch on a leading edge. The thickness of the glass will ultimately determine how close you can get - and remain successful.

IIRC, the general rule for the bare minimum distance from an edge, to drill a hole in a structural member, is **four times its thickness**.

---

(anecdotal supposition)

I've heard that all panes of glass have a sweet spot. I'd assume it lines up with one of the 1/8th harmonic intervals. So on a 24" pane of glass, trying to drill exactly 3" or 6" in could be trouble. But it probably has more to do with how it's mounted, which means for drilling it, it should probably be on some hard plastic, not e.g., on a towel on a table.

Comment: Thanks. If anybody can confidently confirm, deny, or elaborate on these figures, please do.

Answer (score 0):

There are a great number of aquariums , many with similar dimensions with 1 or 2 holes in the bottom, typically 1.5 inch diameter , with no structural problems. And they carry more weight than your terrarium . Actually , you could just get an aquarium , you wouldn't even need a drawing of it.

Comment: How are the holes made? Is there a special technique? Are they drilled, blown, ground, re-annealed, etc? I've never seen one like that before. Not much of a market for that sort of thing where I'm from though. Anyway, the box has actually already been built. I'll keep it in mind for next time though, thanks.